# Creating a string editing macro for Excel Visual Basic

Tags: string, excel, vba

I need help creating a string editing macro for excel in visual basic. I am going to describe what I need to be done but any tiny bit of information would help me if a full answer is not possible. I am creating a redirect list to import into a website. In column A in my excel sheet I have 3,500 URLS that look like this http://www.realitynation.com/tv-shows/snooki-jwoww/drag-queen-lap-dances/17772/attachment/02_shot_jenni_snooki_081-2/ I need to create a redirect list for these pages. The page it needs to redirect to is http://www.realitynation.com/tv-shows/snooki-jwoww/drag-queen-lap-dances/17772/ Look familiar? That is because it is the same URL with the "attachment/..." taken off. I would like to create a macro that can do this for me and place the results in column B. The problem is I have a large background with Java and not Visual Basic, in fact I didn't even know it was possible to do this in Excel until today. Anyway, I'm not asking anyone to solve my problem but any help or direction would be much appreciated. In the mean time I will be researching some string editing in VB to try and figure this out.

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need vba for this. Copy this formula in Cell B1 and copy it down.

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/attachment",A1,1))
```

If you still want VBA then see this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Formula = "=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(""/attachment"",A1,1))"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for making me feel stupid. Thats why I love this site.

Comment: `Thanks for making me feel stupid.` My Apologies. That was never the intention :)